# Customize cron runtime in laravel?

Tags: laravel, cron

I have a file `Commands/DateUpdate.php`

```
protected $signature = 'date:update';
public function handle()
{
    $listSchedule = Schedule::where('dateSchedule', '=', strtotime('now'))->get()->toArray();
    $dateSchedule = [];
    foreach ($listSchedule as $value) {
        $dateSchedule[] = $value['dateSchedule'];
    } 
    var_dump($dateSchedule);
    // result
    // array(3) {
    //     [0]=>
    //     string(16) "2023-01-05 09:16"
    //     [1]=>
    //     string(16) "2023-01-05 11:45"
    //     [2]=>
    //     string(16) "2023-01-05 15:25"
    //   }

}
```

In `Kernel.php`
`$schedule->command('date:update');`
I want to schedule it according to the time in the `$dateSchedule` variable.
Example:

```
foreach ($dateSchedule as $item) {
    ->at($item);
};
```

How can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
foreach ($dateSchedule as $item) {
    $schedule->call(function () {
        $this->call('date:update');
    })->at($item);
};
```

Comment: I think it should be **$listSchedule** as his $dateSchedule is an empty array in the original code.

Comment: @KGG wrote based on example. Maybe He can alter it. Thank you anyway

Comment: How to call `$dateSchedule` variable from Commands to `Kernel.php`?

Answer (score 0):

You can try by compare current time with dateSchedule

```
foreach ($listSchedule as $value) {
  if (now()->diffInMinutes($value['dateSchedule']) === 0) {
    $this->call('another:command');
  }
}
```

Comment: How to call `$dateSchedule` variable from Commands to `Kernel.php`?

Comment: If you want to call schedule list from db, you can execute a command that get these list of schedules and call another command. ... otherwise you can also call query builder from within kernel schedule method , do loop to call $schedule->call('command:update')->at($datetime);